# how to implement kendo autocomplete dropdown in MVC kendo treelist editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-treelist

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d2pL.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNw8u.png)

In this screen, we have used kendo treelist. I need to implement autocomplete dropdown in CODE column. How can i do that?

Comment: Code should be **in the question itself** not an image.

Comment: Look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ac = Html.Kendo()
        .AutoComplete()
        .Name("CodeAutoComplete")
        .DataSource(ds =>
        {
            ds.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Url("youraction");
            });

            ds.ServerFiltering(true);
        });

    var treeGrid = Html.Kendo()
        .TreeList<YourModel>()
        .Name("SomeTreeList")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Field(t => t.YourProperty).Editor(ac.ToHtmlString());
        });
```

Comment: Can't do that as per your sample. Can you give me example. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you see the bottom part, where it shows how to use it with a mvc builders?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my above problem as per given below jquery code.

```
    var input2 = jQuery('<input id="WEIGHT_UOM" value="' + e.model.WEIGHT_UOM + '">');
            input2.appendTo($(".k-grid-edit-row").find("[data-container-for='WEIGHT_UOM']"))
            //create AutoComplete UI component

            $("#WEIGHT_UOM").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataTextField: "ProjectDesc",
                //  template: '${ data.ProjectDesc }' + '<span style="display:none;> ${ data.ProjectDesc }</span>',      
                select: function (org1) {

                    var dataItem1 = this.dataItem(org1.item.index());
                    //   model.set("field1", dataItem.field1);
                    e.model.set("WEIGHT_UOM", dataItem1.ProjectID);

                },
                dataSource: {
                    type: "jsonp",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {

                        read: "@Url.Action("GetISOUnitAutoComp",
                         "DashBoard")",
        }
    }
    });
```